# Play framework - How to write unit test using mockito for promise/response map function?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, mockito, powermock

I am trying to write unit test using mockito + powermock for the following portion of code.

```
WS.WSRequestHolder holder = 
F.Promise<Result> resultPromise = holder.get().map(
    new Function<WS.Response, Result>(){
                @Override
                public Result apply(WS.Response response){
                    return processResponse(response, ctx, watch);
                }
    });
```

I am wondering how can I set expectations and provide mock for holder.get and map function.

Comment: If you find a good way to do this, please share it with us in a new answer, and mark it as the correct answer.